# Looking to launch a local exe on a remote machine without having the resurces on the remote machine

Tags: c#, excel, vba, remote-access

So I have built some code, it's quite simple basically it stops all active input from keyboard and mouse until a text file of a certain name appears in the C:\Temp directory. It also has a manifest file to run it as administrator on start up.

So I found something that on the surface looks like it fulfils my needs of being able to do this task however upon running it I found out that the project has been compiled in x86 and does not run on my x64 machine. Here is the [reference](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9029/Push-and-Run-NET-Code-on-Remote-Machine) to the project if anyone would like to look into it, it's a very smartly designed piece of code that does an interesting objective. It also explains clearly enough what I am trying to accomplish.

So after implementing this (and failing) I have setup a couple other avenues to try, one is VBA through excel with the VBA copying itself to and from the machines in a list and running itself, then there is using VBS to write the entire code as a txt file on the target machine change the extension and then execute it remotely. I have just started researching these but I imagine the problems of running as an administrator amongst other things will crop up again to be dealt with. To be honest though I would really prefer to do this in C# only as that is the language I'm trying to go further in so I'm interested in this challenge. If anybody knows of a similar library of code or application I could look into to achieve what I'm trying I would appreciate being pointed in the right direction.

I would try and be more specific about what libraires/API's im trying to implement but the truth is I don't know what libraries I need to even interact with to get what I want. My goal is to have C# executable code on my machine and a tool that can run that executable on another machine.

Thanks

Comment: Why not compile as x64 then? Is that the problem?

Comment: I have no idea how. Once I download/extract the program source package. Then I am unable to open it in Visual studio it keeps giving a 'project needs to be migrated' error. Is there a setting I can change somewhere on importing/opening the code to allow me to compile the code just fine or is this a problem that resides with the way the code was compiled to begin with?

Comment: Once you have source code it can be compiled to x86 or x64 (unless there are constraints in the libraries used). If you need an x64 executable you should focus on that. Do you actually have source code (solution and project files). This is a very fragmented question I'm not sure if I can help.

Comment: well any direction is appreciate to be honest. It's all a learning curve for me. If you click this link it goes to where you can find the source code so you can see what I have access to. https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9029/Push-and-Run-NET-Code-on-Remote-Machine top of the page is a zip with source in its name. if you inspect that maybe you could compile it on your machine and then guide me on how to replicate that as well?

Comment: When I opened this in VS Express 2015 for Desktop, it offered me a _One Way Upgrade_. I pressed OK. I also pressed OK on security warnings. It popped up a report indicating everything was OK. I pressed Build and it built OK. I Pressed CTRL-F5 to run and it popped up a console window. How about you try getting that far

Comment: I could swear on the moon that I did all of this yesterday more than once and it kept throwing errors when the one-way upgrade window completed. Now it seems to have worked just fine, built and run (which I didn't have an option to build yesterday) Thanks for the help Nick, not sure what the error was yesterday, the only difference is I think git altered some files from being read only to writeable. if you want to put an answer in ill mark it as the right one if you'd like.

Comment: No thats OK it's not really an answer. Glad you sorted that part. It looks like a complex system you're implementing but I suggest you just stick with it and be methodical. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the help in comments from @Nick.McDermaid I was able to correctly open and build the project I was trying to download. Unsure what caused the issue previously with me not being able to open and interact with the code but now I have it I shall pursue this avenue further to accomplish my goal.

As an addendum one other avenue I tried for executing code remotely was through VBS where I used

```
set svcproc=getobject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\"&MachineName & "\root\cimv2:win32_process")
scmd="""C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"" -framemerging ""https://gifyu.com/images/Boo-Ghost-Gif.gif"""
'scmd="C:\Windows\notepad.exe"

iret=svcproc.create(scmd,null,null,pid)
set svcproc=nothing
```

to execute something that existed on the remote machine but I ran into a LOT of security policy issues where I could launch the process but I couldn't bring it to the foreground as the Malware tracker on the machine thought it was an attack and quashed it immediately.